# Where is "search" on the iPod nano 6th gen?

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano

I just won a 6th generation iPod nano at an auction, so I didn't get the box or the instructions. I've mostly figure it out, except I can't figure out where they hid search. I had it on my old nano and it was handy. Is there some arcane double tap or funky gesture I need to use? Unfortunately, trying to search for "search" on the web hasn't been super fruitful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this iPod doesn't have this feature: it's not mentioned in the manual (http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPod_nano_6thgen_User_Guide.pdf) - even in the index.

However, you can go to all items starting with a certain letter.  From the manual (on page 20):

> If the list you’re browsing has an index, drag your finger down the
>   index to show a large letter superimposed over the list. When you
>   reach the letter you want, lift your finger.

Comment: Bleh.  The index is nice *if* you already know the first letter of the song you are looking for.  Unfortunately I don't know the "official" name of all the songs in my library.  I don't understand why they took away such a non intrusive feature, especially when it would have have been one of the rare cases where a touchscreen was better than the clickwheel, which I also miss now that I have been playing with the 6g for a while :(